# Get value of cell using pandas - Python

Tags: python, pandas

I have excell file and I used `table = pd.read_excel('file.xlsx')` in python.
I really can not figure it out how to get concrete content o cell - it must be so simple!

I want to write something like `table['orange]['addr']` and I want to get 0x8080004
or `table['banana']['value']` and get 12

[image]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can do set_index

```
table = table.set_index('name')
```

Then you can do your slice with `loc`

```
table.loc['orange','addr']
'0x8080004'
```